# Project Summary missing from Fortify Audit Workbench 18.20.1071

Tags: fortify, workbench

Question:

Does anyone know how to fix this aside from completely reinstalling the entire Fortify software suite?

Background:

Audit Workbench was up then my PC restarted. Now the Project summary does not show (nor does the code preview).

What I have tried so far:

I tried resetting the display and restarting my PC but it does not bring the Audit Workbench module back.

Previous Fix:

Before when I had this issue, I had to get Fortify completely reinstalled to get it fixed. Because this is on a Government Pc, it will take a while to get it reinstalled. I need this for my job.

Edit: Best Path Forward (Until bug is fixed):

When I open the for through the application (start menu, Fortify SCA folder, Audit Workbench, choose for file), it shows the module. For some reason, a forced restart causes Fortify to not show the module when opening the FPRs directly from the file system.

The other thing is that you cannot pin Audit Workbench to the taskbar which makes this bug more annoying than it should be. I will make a script that I can pin to the taskbar to open the Audit Workbench without going through the start menu every time.

Edit: Found temporary solution

I did a bit of testing and whenever I open the FPR with Audit Workbench, I need to open 2 windows, 1 immediately after the other, to get the project summary back. The first one I open will not show the Project Summary but the 2nd one will. It only shows the pane on the 2nd window for some reason.

Comment: This seems more suitable to a bug report. At least I can't detect any programming-related question here. Just in case, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check question for "Path Forward"

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your own question? It seems to extend on it, for which you should edit that question instead. See above comment though.

Comment: It is the best "path forward" answer I could provide based on searches throughout the internet. This is something that was asked before on many sites by other people. The questions never had an answer which left me stuck for a while and left me with the option of reinstalling Fortify SCA to fix one module. I will put in a bug report once I can get the error logs showing what is happening.

Comment: I am moving the answer into the question in case anyone comes by the same issue. This big is never mentioned much because of the low chance of it happening (even though this is the 2nd time it has happened to me). With no suitable answers/responses to get around this, it leaves many with very little option but to reinstall to fix it.